# C# Launching another WPF program from a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, .net-assembly, appdomain

First of all, let me say that I've looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328200/load-a-wpf-application-assembly-from-another-wpf-app-get-error-cannot-create-m), and i still haven't been able to find a great solution to my problem. (I will elaborate in post)

Now to the point.
I have a program which I want to secure with a login.
My setup is as follows:

*Login.exe*

*Application.exe* (Gathered from server into byte[])

The user should login, and when successfully logged in, get the server file (Application.exe) and run it, however this file must **not** be stored locally on the users machine. Instead, this file, which is stored as a byte array, should be launched as a program, but, if possible, not with a location on the harddrive.

Here's how the user would see it:

- First they'd get the login application, login and the application
  would download the file from server, and execute it.

Now the main problem i've been struggling with is, that whenever i load this byte array, i get the following Exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: The destination of an activation triggered an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Can not create more than one instance of System.Windows.Application in the same AppDomain.
```

I've tried with multiple ways, but I've always ended up with the following code:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(tmpbytearray);
MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
if (method != null)
{
    object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
    method.Invoke(o, null);
}
```

I've also tried with

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(tmpsrc);
//entrypoint: MyMainApplication.App.Main
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyMainApplication.App");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
type.InvokeMember("Main",
    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    obj,
    null);
```

But still stuck with the same Exception.

As I've read through the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328200/load-a-wpf-application-assembly-from-another-wpf-app-get-error-cannot-create-m) (Section B and C) from the top I've also seen the usage of CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap, but as I can't find a way to supply it with a byte array, instead of a file path, I've decided not to go that way. 
Now I'm back to square one, and therefore asking here in my last hopes to sum up a solution to this project.

If i've made some misunderstandings throughout the post, feel free to ask, as I will do my best to be as clear and understandable as possible.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE (*Maybe* another approach)**
I've now thought of making a small console based application, which would act as a "launcher" for this application. However this also gives an exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: The destination of an activation triggered an exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: The resource mainwindow.xaml was not found.
```

This exception is really weird, as the application itself works when ran. So the following:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(tmpsrc);
MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
if (method != null)
{
    object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
    method.Invoke(o, null); //Exception.
}
```

Depending on what might be the most easy solution, what would you prefer, and how would you think of a possible solution to any of the approaches (The second, or first approach)?

Comment: This exception complains about a second instance of the `Application`. You might try to create a new domain and load the assembly in it. You should take a look over here: [Loading/Unloading assembly in different AppDomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132649/loading-unloading-assembly-in-different-appdomain)

Comment: A good reference indeed, but may I ask how i would be able to add the byte array manually, instead of applying a file path to the appdomainsetup, because this does not seem to be a possibility as far as I am aware?

Comment: Create an intermediate assembly that contains a class with a method that accepts the byte array. This method should load the assembly from the byte array. Load this intermediate assembly in a new domain.

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot mark this as complete, but this question has now been solved)

So, some struggles later, I've finally managed to get this working.

I ended up trying many things, but the solution for me was based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429917/load-wpf-application-from-the-memory) question.

I took the loader class in my Login Application and added the rest after the login has been authorized successfully:

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test");
domain.Load("Login");

var loader = (Loader)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("Login", "Login.Loader");
loader.Load(tmpsrc);
```

After that it somehow worked, which i'm quite surprised for. But anyways, thanks for the help and pinpoints into the proper subjects!