# How to load a wpf exe and start it by reflection in the same process and appdomain?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection

I'm using TinyJitHook https://github.com/Elliesaur/TinyJitHook to patch a compiled executable file.

I want to load a wpf exe file and run it in a c# console program;

The wpf program is the default empty window of visual studio.

The main program is a console program;

When I run the main program, I get a "Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'" error.

What should I do.

Thanks to the people who made the "Process.Start("WpfApp1.exe")"  comments, this starts the program, but that doesn't seem to make them in one process or AppDomain.

#### mainApp

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = @"WpfApp1.exe";

    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
    MainJitHook hook = new MainJitHook(asm, IntPtr.Size == 8);
    hook.OnCompileMethod += ChangeExample;

    hook.Hook();
    try
    {
        MethodInfo method = asm.EntryPoint;
        method.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
    }
    catch (Exception extInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(extInfo.ToString());
    }

    hook.Unhook();
    Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    Console.ReadKey();
}


private static unsafe void ChangeExample(MainJitHook.RawArguments args, Assembly relatedAssembly, uint methodToken, ref byte[] ilBytes1, ref byte[] ehBytes1)
{
    try
    {
        var methodBase = relatedAssembly.ManifestModule.ResolveMethod((int) methodToken);
        Console.WriteLine("###################### cur method is " + methodBase.Name + " asm fiel is " + relatedAssembly.GetName());
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

#### App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Error

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)

    ...
    ...

   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at WpfApp1.App.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at TinyJitHook.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\download\TinyJitHook-master\TinyJitHook\Program.cs:line 42
```

Comment: `Process.Start("WpfApp1.exe")`?

Comment: And what is your expectation here ? Why would you assume that you can load a GUI app inside a console app. What you want to achieve may work for dll files, not for exe files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load WPF application from the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429917/load-wpf-application-from-the-memory)

Comment: the wpf program is already compiled by someone. So I can't get the dll.

Comment: It seems the same question with <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429917/load-wpf-application-from-the-memory>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a compiled WPF application executable, you could use the `Process.Start` API to run it in a separate process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"WpfApp1.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the program does start. I didn't describe it clearly, if using process.start(), It will in different process or appdomain. I edited the description, is there a way to solve it in this case.

Comment: Why do you even use a console application if you want to start the WPF application in the same process? Then implement your code in the WPF app directly?

Comment: Because the wpf program is already compiled by someone else, I want to make some changes to it

Comment: So why do you want to run it at all then? The changes need to be implemented before you start the process.

Comment: It has static integrity check and is very obfuscated...

Comment: Well, you don't "start" anything in the current process unless this is part of the process. If you want a modified version of an app, you need to implement one.

Comment: ok i got it, thanks

Comment: I haven't solved my problem yet. This <https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337723/11639899> answer may helps me, but it didn't work either.

Comment: You can't solve the issue of recompiling an app by trying to start in an existing process. Your approach doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If I use easyhook <https://easyhook.github.io/> to modify the compileMethod of JIT, will it work to modify the opcode in it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can't start an exe in one process. I will try another way.